# Sum in window form application in c# Invalid operation exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
string queryn2 = null;
queryn2 = "SELECT  SUM (product_complete)  AS productcomplete,SUM(product_incomplete)  AS productincomplete,SUM(amount) AS amount  from intern_planuser where orderitem = '" + textBox15.Text + "' and vendername = '" + vendernamelist[0] + "'";

SqlCommand cmdn3 = new SqlCommand(queryn2, con5);
SqlDataReader drn3 = cmdn3.ExecuteReader();

d1 = 0;

while (drn3.Read())
{
    sumproductcomplete[d1] = drn3.GetInt32(0);
    sumproductcompletet[d1] = Convert.ToString(sumproductcompletet[d1]);
    sumproductincomplete[d1] = drn3.GetInt32(1);
    sumproductincompletet[d1] = Convert.ToString(sumproductincompletet[d1]);

    sumproductamount[d1] = drn3.GetInt32(2);
    d1++;
    // productincomplete = Convert.ToInt32(drn2["productincomplete"]);
}

drn3.Close();

sumproductlost[0] = sumproductamount[0] - sumproductcomplete[0] - sumproductincomplete[0];
sumproductlostt[0] = Convert.ToString(sumproductlostt);

label14.Text = sumproductcompletet[0];
label68.Text = sumproductincompletet[0];
label42.Text = sumproductlostt[0];
```

I got the error while I use sum statement. I've already try to query from SQL, it works, but when I execute the code, I get an error

> Invalid operation exception was unhandled .

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Which statement throws the exception? And please post full code.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: And just in case you live long enough till the invention of time travel, use meaningful variable names, or the future you will come and hit you on the head.